# Raycast detection from GameObject to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created current setup:
[image]

Which basically is two grids, where the back one will be invisible (disabled render), but I've left it in for context.

The goal is to create a raycast from each tile in the back-grid, which detects if theres something in front of it, then changes that tiles tag.

My code looks the following:

```
 int tileNumber = 0;
        for (float y = 0; y > mapHeight; y--)
        {
            for (float x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
                GameObject go = Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(x/3, y/3, -2), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                tileNumber++;
                go.name = "tile" + tileNumber;
                go.tag = "grid";
                
                RaycastHit hit;
                Vector3 fwd = go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
                Debug.DrawRay(go.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);
                if(Physics.Raycast(go.transform.position, fwd, out hit, 200)){
                    go.tag = "walkableGrid";
                }
                
            }
        }
```

But the Debug ray doesn't even show, and the tag doesn't change either.

Image that shows the rays are indeed working, just not detecting my map grid:
[image]

EDIT: Programmer tried to help me, but his solution didn't work for me. He's mentioned the issue might lie elsewhere, so if anyone is interested as he is, heres my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/535soeswrgq37b4/MTA16336_Project_Boardgame.rar?dl=0

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to work. Not even the debug shows up" There is no Debug.Log in your code.....What doesn't work and what work?

Comment: I believe "Debug.DrawRay(go.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);" should show a visible ray

Comment: Yeah but that depends on how often the it is called. It will be hard to see if it is not called every frame. You need to also add Debug.Log to make sure that part of code is being reached.

Comment: My bad, I tried drawing it through the Update(). Checked with DrawRay and Debug.Log. The ray definetely hits my object, but the if(Physics...) loop apparently doesn't get reached. Maybe my issue lies in using Physics.Raycast?

Comment: **"The goal is to create a raycast from each tile in the back-grid, which detects if theres something above it, then changes that tiles tag"** If this is true then `go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);` should be `go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);`

Comment: Bad wording from my part. As seen on my image, the "up" part is actually aligned with the Z-axis

Comment: You want to upload an image that draws a error on what you consider to be up and forward? Right right now, up = y+, down = y-. Unless I am missing something else...

Comment: When it's set to 2D the depth is in the z-axis, which is Vector3.forward. I'm adding a picture that shows the rays drawn using .forward. It's worth nothing that none of my "Map" objects neither have a rigibody nor a collider. I tried creating a collider for one of the objects as a test, but same result.

Comment: Is this a 2D or 3D game? Also, the images, are they UI Image or SpriteRenderer?

Comment: It's a 2d, using the advantage of 3D to detect. The images are square sprites, gathered in an empty object as one, then another empty object to manipulate the pivot point. 3 to 5 squares>EmptyObject>EmptyObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's worth nothing that none of my "Map" objects neither have a
>   rigibody nor a collider.

`Physics.Raycast` will **never** work without a collider.

Since this is a 2D game, you have to use *Box collider 2D*. 
Also, attach `Rigidbody 2D` to it.

Finally, `Physics.Raycast` is only used with **none** 2D colliders. You have to replace that with `RaycastHit2D.Raycast`. Also, `RaycastHit` should be replaced `RaycastHit2D`.

To make it easier, simply change:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 fwd = go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(go.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);
if (Physics.Raycast(go.transform.position, fwd, out hit, 200))
{
    go.tag = "walkableGrid";
}
```

to

```
RaycastHit2D hit;
Vector3 fwd = go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(go.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);
hit = Physics2D.Raycast(go.transform.position, fwd, 200);

if (hit)
{
    go.tag = "walkableGrid";
}
```

This should now work as long as `Box Collider 2D` is attached to each block. Also attach `Rigidbody 2D` to them. If it is falling down, set the *Gravity Scale* to `0`.

Comment: I've used your exact code, added a rigidbody, tested with both edge-collider and box-collider, but the code still doesn't reach the code inside the if bracket. Does it still work as 2D detection, when I convert the objects into GameObjects in my instantiation?

Comment: "Does it still work as 2D detection, when I convert the objects into GameObjects in my instantiation?" Yes. Remember, I said `Box Collider 2D` **not** `Box Collider`. These are totally different stuff.

Comment: I am currently using an EdgeCollider2D, which gave that result. Then tested with a Box Collider2D, still same result. I wish I could give more information, but that's all I can figure.

Comment: And also Rigidbody2D not Rigidbody. If this is what you did then there is something else that is going on. Please upload your project somewhere and put the link here. I will take a look at it. Note that you should be using `Box Collider 2D` for this not `EdgeCollider2D`. I don't know why you keep mentioning that.

Comment: If I use box collider it will select the complete 3x3 area. I need it to only select the squares that make the object. I'll upload my complete project, and add it as an edit, thanks.

Comment: Link to project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/535soeswrgq37b4/MTA16336_Project_Boardgame.rar?dl=0

Comment: Programmers solution works, my issue relied in putting my Collider on the parent empty object, when I needed to put it on the individual squares the object was made of.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was not able to run this because I don't have access to my non working machine.Not allowed to run other projects on my working machine. I was gonna reply today when I try it. Glad you solved it. +1

Comment: Btw: Raycasts do not require the target to have a Rigidbody, they'll hit it anyway.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert That's correct but I recommended adding `Rigidbody` because there is a bug that prevents raycast from working. This is usually fixed by attaching `Rigidbody` to the collider. I've had this problem before and many people like [this person](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/raycast-on-colliders-without-rigidbodies.57913/) had the-same problem too. The bug is not yet fixed and can happen randomly. Once `Rigidbody` is attached to the collider, it fixes and then you can remove it from the collider. I put that in the answer to cover that bug.

Comment: Hm. Not sure if it's advisable to add a workaround for a bug that very few people will ever have to a standard solution. Maybe that bug is better treated in a seperate Question and Answer?

Comment: OP has tried almost everything but said it doesn't work. Adding that makes sure nothing else missing.There is nothing wrong with having `Rigidbody` attached to the GameObject.